# Recursive Dirichlet convolutions and sum errors

Tags: recursion, number-theory

I only have an informal knowledge of mathematical at best, learned entirely from modifying premade programs, and reading the documentation of functions, so I apologize if my question should be obvious or inane. Currently, I'm trying to mess around with Dirichlet powers of arithmetic functions, and to do this I'm using Mathematica. I have the following code, but I keep getting errors about various objects not being able to be used as iterators.

```
f[1, x_] := MoebiusMu[x];
f[n_, x_] := DirichletConvolve[f[1, d], f[n - 1, d], d, x];
Table[f[i, 2], {i, 0, 5}]
```

I assume that this is caused by the effectively nested `DirichletConvolution`s, as I've run into similar errors in the past, and fixed them by making sure that the iterators had different names for each layer, but I don't think that's a viable solution here. Furthermore, based on the errors, I assume that this runs deeper into the implementation of the `DirichletConvolution` function with `Sum`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps.  This is certainly not a stupid question as it depends on some subtle behaviour that took me some time to figure out.

A simple problem first.  You don't define `f[0,x]` so you have an infinite recursion.  I've modified it so that it only recurses for `n>1` (and changed the lower limit on the table).

The other problem is that Mathematica gets confused by the fact that the same symbol `d` is reused at different levels of recursion.  The way round this is to use `Module` to declare it as a local variable.

With these fixes, I get

```
f[1, x_] := MoebiusMu[x];
f[n_ /; n > 1, x_] := 
  Module[{d}, DirichletConvolve[f[1, d], f[n - 1, d], d, x]];

Table[f[i, 2], {i, 1, 5}]
(* {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful! For some reason, it never occurred to me that Mathematica would have different levels of scope. Also, the end result was certainly not what I was expecting.